# Customizing kdm Ghost Theme in Kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, plasma, gdm3, kdm

I am using Kali Linux and just switched to kdm plasma desktop from gnome. I installed the futuristic ghost theme. As we get wifi and recording icons at the top right of desktop in gnome, i couldn't find a way to pin these icons in kdm desktop. How can i find these wifi , recording icons and pin them in the task bar in kdm ghost themed desktop in kali linux?

this is my current desktop :

[image]

and this is the style i want it, as you can see wifi and recording icons at the top right corner :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this by installing network manager package for kdm plasma.